# why volume property doesn't work on ZUNE objects in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, zune

I'm facing a very odd problem here, it seems like reducing or any action taken on the Volume property of the MediaPlayer static class doesn't make any difference. I've heard somewhere that microsoft protected it but it doesn't make any sense that in iPhone & Android you can do it, but in windows phone 7 it's impossible.

```
MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.2F;
```

what am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the phone's global volume. Actually it makes difference, you just haven't notice it - it behaves as a scale for your music, so this goes like this:

System sound * MediaPlayer.Volume * What you are playing.

One does not simply look into MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx